# Bold subscripts

Tags: bold

I would like my subscript `y_{ij}` in bold. I used:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\bf{y}_{ij} 
\end{document}
```

or

```
\mathbf{y}_{ij}
```

but really nothing happens. Only `y` is in bold.

Can anyone help me please?

Best

Comment: Try `$y_{\text{\bfseries\itshape ij}}$` but I honestly don't see the application of bolding the subscript.

Comment: Thank you a lot azetina. You're right as a matter of fact I would like to bold y too. Simply adding {\textbf{y}}_... it works perfectly! Thank you again!

Comment: @elb If you want math bold, use `\mathbf{y_{ij}}` instead of the `\text` stuff. To see the difference compare `\textsf{$\mathbf{y_{ij}}$}` and `\textsf{$\textbf{y}_{\text{\bfseries\itshape ij}}$}`.

Answer (score 9):

The context is not very clear to me: math formula with bold symbols,
math formula in bold context like section titles, bold/italics or bold/upright, text mode, ...

Here some variations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}% for \textsubscript
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
  $y_{ij}$, \boldmath{$y_{ij}$}, $\bm{y_{ij}}$,
  $\mathbf{y_{ij}}$, \textbf{y\textsubscript{ij}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]