# How do I make mu bold and not the subscript?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

I'm not sure how to do this and have spent a long time trying.

I looked at a previous post on this:  [Bold subscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194174/bold-subscripts)

It is slightly different but, I still can't get it to work.

My code:

```
\begin{equation} 
p(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{n=1}^{K} \pi_k \mathcal{N}
(\textbf{x}|\mathbf{\mu}_{k},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{k})
\end{equation}
```

[image]

As you can see, I can get the sigma in bold, but not the mu?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using bold to represent something, for instance a vector, I would define a command `\newcommand*\vector[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` and that way you get clearer code an easy to change. In any case, for `\mu` you would be better using `\bm` from `bm` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your title is misleading: You don't want to `capitalize but to get a bold `\mu`.

Comment: @Manuel Wow. \bm worked. Thanks so much! I spent nearly an hour on this LOL -.o

Comment: the `\mathbf` is not expected to do anything good on `\mu` in traditional pdflatex context. You can use also `\boldsymbol{\mu}` if using amsmath. Admittedly your `\mathbf{\Sigma}` works... turns out indeed that in the default setting `\Sigma` is of variable family type but not `\mu`.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding an answer for a remark (the OP got the answer from @Manuel's comment to use `\bm` from `bm` package; one can also use `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath` package).

The remark here is that there was a problem with `\mu` but not with `\Sigma`. Why?

The point is that the cmr font contains 11 uppercase greek letters in slots 0 to 10, in the OT1 encoding. This is a bizarre legacy, but it does make `\mathbf{\Sigma}` work. I.e. the font used for operator names (`log`, `sin`, `cos`,...) also contains the uppercase (non-Latin) Greek letters. The idea of the `\math..` alphabet commands is to use the *text* font in math mode. That it works for those 11 Greek letters is counter-intuitive and bound to the OT1 encoding used by the "operator" font. It is not robust against changes of the "operator" font.

Hence I would not recommend using `\mathbf{\Sigma}`, because it twists too much the idea of the LaTeX NFSS math alphabet commands. It ties it to peculiarity of Knuth's OT1 encoding.

Comment: Yeah, although the problem was solved the mystery was not solved. Thanks for the explanation!